# setting Technical profile > Browser name for iOS Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics

Is there any way to change the Browser name from Visitors>Overview>Technical Profile> Browser in iOS? As default it's "GoogleAnalytics".

The reason why I am asking this is because for Android there is

```
GoogleAnalyticsTracker mTracker;
mTracker.setProductVersion(productName, productVersion);
```

But I couldn't find any for iOS...